# ReactJS/Javascript: map function and rendering

Tags: java, reactjs, react-apollo, graphql-js

[image]The Graph component is getting data (verified in console) but for some reason the page is still blank.  I am not quit sure I understand how the map function works.  This is the last piece I need to figure out to render this graph but for whatever reason I can't seem to get any graphics on the screen.  The state of nodes in the console is:

```
{data: {action: [{action: "Changed", timestamp: 1499348050,…},…]}}
    data:{action: [{action: "Changed", timestamp: 1499348050,…},…]}
      action:[{action: "User Assist Changed", timestamp: 1499348050,…},…]
```

Graph Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import {graphql} from 'react-apollo';
import getObjectsQuery from './Queries';

class Graph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {  startTime:this.props.startTime, 
                    endTime:this.props.endTime,
                    nodes:this.props.getObjectsQuery
                  }
    //console.log('graph data:', this.props.data)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   console.log('nodes:', this.props.data)
    this.force = d3.forceSimulation(this.props.data)
      .force("charge",
        d3.forceManyBody()
          .strength(this.props.forceStrength)
      )
      .force("x", d3.forceX(this.props.width / 2))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(this.props.height / 2));

    this.force.on('tick', () => this.setState({nodes: this.props.data}));
    console.log('setState:', this.props.data);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.force.stop();
  }

    render() {
   // console.log('graph datas:', this.props.data)
    return (

      <svg width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height}>

      {Object.keys(this.props.data).map((action, index) =>(
     <circle r={action.action} cx={action.second} cy={action.obj} fill="red" key={index}/>
      ))}
      </svg>
    );
  }//render
}//Component

export default graphql(getObjectsQuery, 
  { options: (ownProps) => { 
    console.log(ownProps.startTime); 
    return ({ second: { startTime: ownProps.startTime,
                            endTime: ownProps.endTime
     } }) 
  } } )(Graph);

  Graph.defaultProps = {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    forceStrength: -10
  };
```

Comment: Share the complete json structure

Comment: `{variables: {…}, refetch: ƒ, fetchMore: ƒ, updateQuery: ƒ, startPolling: ƒ, …} action: Array(1072) [0 … 99]--new line here--- 0: {action: "Changed", timestamp: 1499348050000, object: Array(1), Second: Array(1), __typename: "action", …}`

Comment: I meant this.props.data

Comment: I just added a picture of it to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If `this.props.data.action` is an array then it can be used directly in map:

```
{this.props.data.action.map((action,
```

but `this.props.data.action` (and even `this.props.data`?) can be undefined on start, first render

use some conditions in render to prevent errors, f.e.

```
{!this.props.data.loading && this.props.data.action.map((action,
```

Check if `loading` is present ... structure of props passed into component can be mapped differently by fn defined in config `props` property in `graphql()` (f.e. in case of conflict props names). **Search for examples.**